# Mountain Lion, Tap to Click and Two Finger Scroll Problems

Tags: macos

I'm using a macbook air with mountain lion 10.8.2. An interesting problem has recently started occurring with using the built in trackpad.

If I use two finger scrolls 9/10 times it sees this as a right-click and bring up the context menu, occasionally when I have just one finger resting on the trackpad it treats this as a single left-click. Tap to click is disabled within the System Preferences.

Has anyone encountered this problem before or knows of a solution?

Thank

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with your trackpad not registering everything correctly, or a very slow computer. A way to fix this, but you would have to change the way you bring up the context menu, is to open System Preferences, navigate to Trackpad > Point & Click. Next, you can either disable it by clicking the checkbox next to it, which means you would then have to Control+Click for the context menu. You can also click on the down arrow next to "Click or tap with two fingers" and select one of the other options. Sorry there's no real solution to your problem.